# How to fix jest/no-standalone-expect coming from Cypress test?

Tags: jestjs, cypress, eslint

I have E2E Cypress tests and they all pass. However this one gives me a `jest/no-standalone-expect` ESLint error:

```
Then(/^I should see a headline "(.+)"/, title => {
  cy.get('@Request').then((interception: unknown) => {
    const interceptedRequest = interception;
    cy.get(stuff[title]).then(heading => {
      expect(heading).to.match(new RegExp(interceptedRequest.thing)); 
    })
  });
});
```

I have similar uses of `expect` in other tests without issues. How do I fix this one and what's causing the issue?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: This is the error `error  Expect must be inside of a test block  jest/no-standalone-expect`

Comment: You shouldn't be running the Jest rules on your Cypress tests, they don't really apply. Use e.g. `overrides` to apply the [appropriate rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-cypress) to your E2E tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually solved my issue - extracting the `expect` into a helper function.

```
Then(/^I should see a headline "(.+)"/, title => {
  const matchHelper = (text, test) => {
    expect(text).to.match(test)
  }
  cy.get('@Request').then((interception: unknown) => {
    const interceptedRequest = interception;
    cy.get(stuff[title]).then(heading => {
      matchHelper(heading, new RegExp(interceptedRequest.thing)); 
    })
  });
});
```

It's one of the suggestions from the official [docs](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/main/docs/rules/no-standalone-expect.md), but still doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: If you do want to use this rule, why not use `additionalTestBlockFunctions` to tell it `Then` is also a test?